# Why FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() is returning null

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I’m reprogramming/reproducing whatsapp for android and I’m facing a problem.

In my app, users have to register their self to use it. After the registration, users are directed to the MainActivity where they can start chatting with their friends or they can complete their profile. Users can Login to the app but only if they Logout. They don't have to Login after the registration.

I'm using the Firebase technologies, Firebase Authentication, Firebas database, Firebase storage on the app. When the user complete his registration, his information are stored in the real-time database.

Here's the problem I registered my self and instead of going directly to the MainActivity, i'm directed to LoginActivity and that can  happen only if
the currentUser is null. If the currentUser is null, it means that FirebasAuth.getCurrentUser() is returning null.

I want to understand why is this hapenning ? Why my currentUser variable is null when I registered my self only few seconds ago ? Why is `FirebasAuth.getCurrentUser()`
returning `null` when i can see that my informations are stored on the Firebase database?

Here's the code of RegisterActivity :

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button createUser;
private EditText registerEmail, registerPassword;
private TextView haveAccount;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference RootRef;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    RootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    initializeFields();
    haveAccount.setClickable(true);
    haveAccount.setFocusable(true);

    haveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
    });

    createUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNewAccount();
        }
    });
}





private void createNewAccount() {
    final String email=registerEmail.getText().toString();
    String password=registerPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter an address mail to create an account",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an address mail to create an account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Create new Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we creating account for you");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth=new FirebaseAuth(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(RegisterActivity.this));
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String currentUserID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(email);

                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Your account is created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();

                }
                else {

                    String message=task.getException().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Error " + message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}

private void initializeFields() {
    createUser=findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    registerEmail=findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    registerPassword=findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    haveAccount=findViewById(R.id.already_have_account_link);

    loadingBar= new ProgressDialog(this);
}

private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
    StartActivity(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
}

private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    StartActivity(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
}

private void StartActivity(Context c, Class<?> activity){
    Intent i=new Intent(c,activity);
    if(activity.equals(MainActivity.class)) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else
        startActivity(i);
}
```

And here's the code of my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager myViewPager;
private TabLayout myTabLayout;
private TabsAccessorAdapter myTabsAccessorAdapter;

private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference RootRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    RootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsApp");

    myViewPager=findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
    myTabsAccessorAdapter=new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabsAccessorAdapter);

    myTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_find_friends_option){

    }

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_create_group_option){

        requestNewGroup();
    }

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_settings_option){
        SendUserToSettingsActivity();
    }

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_logout_option){
        mAuth.signOut();
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser==null)
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    else
        verifyUserID();
}

private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
    StartActivity(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
}

private void StartActivity(Context c, Class<?> activity){
    Intent i=new Intent(c,activity);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating or signing in the user, it takes a brief moment before `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` picks up this change. So if you're using that variable in the meantime, you will get `null`.

There are two options to work around this:

1. Use the `Task<AuthResult> task` that you get after creating the user. So `String currentUserID=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();` and pass that along to the new activity in the intent.
2. Use an `AuthStateListener` to pick up the authentication state in the next activity.

   ```
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
           FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
           if (user != null) {
               // Sign in logic here.
           }
       }
   };)
   ```

Comment: i changed my onStart method to this but it's still not working.


{  protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (currentUser == null)
                    SendUserToLoginActivity();
                else
                    verifyUserID();
            }
        });
}

Comment: sorry for this comment i don't know how to put code correctly in the comments